# What is the best Math Font for use with Minion Pro font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, fontspec

I have began using the Minion Pro series of fonts and compiling with XeLaTeX. However, despite the typeface changing, I still have the same CM Modern Math fonts. Do any of you have a good suggestion for a good math font that works with Minion Pro?

I have used `\usepackage{mathastext}` and the italic varient `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}` but the 'f' in math mode is very awkward and too close to the parethesis. The code that produces this effects is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
This is the standard Minion Pro Font\ldots My issue is with the 'f' in italic math mode. It needs more space. For example:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^2 + f(n-1) 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is there a better option than `\usepackage{mathastext}`? or is there a way to adjust this minor issue? I have never been able to get `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` working (I keep getting a Command `\mathdollar` already defined error) and Minion Math is well... pricey.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: the answers provide specific `Minion` packages which are presumably a better choice; but for the record let me mention that you can issue `\MTsetmathskips {f}{0mu}{1mu}` to have extra white space of `1mu` automatically inserted in math mode after each `f`. (adjust this to the value of your taste)

Comment: Pricey is an understatement.

Comment: I too suggest "MnSymbol" is the best combination with MinionPro...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest to use the `MinionPro` package. It works under XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX. It is part  of the Font Pro package available from https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro. Follow the instructions there to install it.

The  following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
This is the standard Minion Pro Font\ldots My issue is with the 'f' in italic math mode. It needs more space. For example:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^2 + f(n-1) 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Another solution is to use the `MnSymbols` package. To avoid the problem with the `\mathdollar already defined error` one can use the following workaround.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

% the next line makes the definition of \mathdollar from MnSymbol void.
\undef\mathdollar 

% the next 3 lines reinstate the definition of \mathdollar from MnSymbols 
% at the begin  of the document
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathdollar{\Mn@Text@With@MathVersion{\textdollar}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Under xetex, you can use fontspec and the command \setmainfont{Minion Pro} in order to use the opentype font for text, and load the MinionPro package with the ‘onlymath’ option.

Comment: I have looked at the MinionPro package before, I just wanted something that was more "independent" than a downloaded package and faster to work with. Preferably something that comes with CTAN. +1 for finding a great match however.

Comment: The workaround for the `\mathdollar` command was perfect and I just got the MinionPro Package working - it is gorgeous. Is it necessary to redefine `\mathdollar` it if it is not going to be used?

Comment: No, you can leave out the definition of `\mathdollar`. In such case it will resort  to the original one (and you can notice the different font for $ with the two solutions).

Comment: If I use `\usepackage{MinionPro}`or `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`together with the fontspec package und lualatex I only get Latin Modern Math font. Thus this solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 15):

André Miede, the author of `classicthesis` - which uses Minion Pro, recommends the Euler Math font to use with the latter one:

> "[...]  loads the *awesome* Euler fonts for math." [emphesis mine]

(from the `classicthesis` documentation, page 6)

Comment: This has an OTF version: https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf

Answer (score 7):

According to the German Wikipedia article there is a Minion Math font by Typoma, specifically designed for Minion Pro.

Find more information on their homepage at http://www.typoma.com/de/schriften.html

Comment: The OP explicitly mentions Minion Math.

Answer (score 3):

When using Overleaf, I could not use the `MinionPro` package or the `Mnsymbol`. For math font, I found `mathpazo` to look relatively similar to `Minion Pro` and an adequate replacement.

---

**Minion Pro vs Mathpazzo**

[image]

**Minion Pro vs Euler** (as recommended by another answer)

[image]

**Matpazo symbols in Minion Pro text** (the V, S and K in the text are in math mode, so in Mathpazo)

[image]

---

To load them, use the following code. Order is important.

```latex
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular.otf}[
  BoldFont       = MinionPro-Bold.otf,
  ItalicFont     = MinionPro-It.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = MinionPro-BoldIt.otf
]
```

Comment: Excuse me. It is mathpazo and not mathpazzo.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.3, `mathastext` has the command `\MTsetmathskips`, that you can correct the spacing for the letters which are weird, such as the f on MinionPro.