# Minion Pro and fontspec - how to get math fonts

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math, minionpro

I have the minion otf fonts installed in the windows font folder.
This enables me to load the fonts using fontspec.
But I have no math fonts. How can I enable math fonts with fontspec loading mechanism und lualatex?

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}

\begin{document}
        
    \chapter*{Font Test}
    The text on these pages demonstrates the appearance of the used fonts for serif, \textsf{sans serif}, math and \texttt{typewriter fonts}. 
    %
    \subsection*{Green's theorem}
    \begin{equation}
        \underset{\mathcal{G}\quad}\iiint
        \left[u\nabla^{2}v+\left(\nabla  u,\nabla  v\right)\right]\mathrm{d}^{3}V
        =\underset{\mathcal{S}\quad}\oiint  u\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}
        \,\,\mathrm{d}^{2}A
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145522/1090 for free math fonts to go with Minion

Comment: And use the unicode-math command `\setmathfont` to load a specific math font by hand: e.g., `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}`.

Comment: Look in `...\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\public` for the ones that come with TeX, e.g., `...\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\public\tex-gyre-math` has five. There are others: asana, fira, etc.